# Solr hang while DIH working, logs say nothing

Tags: solr

Hi! I try to upload index from Postgres. Solr hang while DIH working. I tried to read logs, but they say nothing about any errors.

this is my tail of solr.log

```
2019-08-16 11:17:10.301 INFO  (qtp988850650-22) [   x:db] o.a.s.c.S.Request [db]  webapp=/solr path=/dataimport params={indent=on&wt=json&command=status&_=1565948855825} status=0 QTime=0
2019-08-16 11:17:13.206 INFO  (qtp988850650-41) [   x:db] o.a.s.c.S.Request [db]  webapp=/solr path=/dataimport params={indent=on&wt=json&command=status&_=1565948855825} status=0 QTime=1
2019-08-16 11:17:15.690 INFO  (qtp988850650-22) [   x:db] o.a.s.c.S.Request [db]  webapp=/solr path=/dataimport params={indent=on&wt=json&command=status&_=1565948855825} status=0 QTime=2
2019-08-16 11:17:16.431 INFO  (qtp988850650-41) [   x:db] o.a.s.c.S.Request [db]  webapp=/solr path=/dataimport params={indent=on&wt=json&command=status&_=1565948855825} status=0 QTime=1
2019-08-16 11:17:18.838 INFO  (qtp988850650-22) [   x:db] o.a.s.c.S.Request [db]  webapp=/solr path=/dataimport params={indent=on&wt=json&command=status&_=1565948855825} status=0 QTime=1
```

tail of solr_gc.log

```
    [2019-08-16T14:09:12.819+0300][4905,856s] GC(83) Eden regions: 1009->0(999)
[2019-08-16T14:09:12.819+0300][4905,856s] GC(83) Survivor regions: 79->73(136)
[2019-08-16T14:09:12.819+0300][4905,856s] GC(83) Old regions: 611->635
[2019-08-16T14:09:12.819+0300][4905,856s] GC(83) Humongous regions: 64->29
[2019-08-16T14:09:12.819+0300][4905,856s] GC(83) Metaspace: 52813K->52813K(1097728K)
[2019-08-16T14:09:12.820+0300][4905,857s] GC(83) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 7049M->2942M(8192M) 397,839ms
[2019-08-16T14:09:12.820+0300][4905,857s] GC(83) User=0,16s Sys=0,05s Real=0,39s
[2019-08-16T14:14:32.330+0300][5225,367s] GC(84) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause)
[2019-08-16T14:14:32.609+0300][5225,646s] GC(84) Using 4 workers of 4 for evacuation
[2019-08-16T14:14:32.680+0300][5225,717s] GC(84)   Pre Evacuate Collection Set: 0,5ms
[2019-08-16T14:14:32.680+0300][5225,718s] GC(84)   Evacuate Collection Set: 67,9ms
[2019-08-16T14:14:32.680+0300][5225,718s] GC(84)   Post Evacuate Collection Set: 2,3ms
[2019-08-16T14:14:32.680+0300][5225,718s] GC(84)   Other: 279,5ms
[2019-08-16T14:14:32.680+0300][5225,718s] GC(84) Eden regions: 999->0(1006)
[2019-08-16T14:14:32.681+0300][5225,718s] GC(84) Survivor regions: 73->65(134)
[2019-08-16T14:14:32.681+0300][5225,718s] GC(84) Old regions: 635->637
[2019-08-16T14:14:32.681+0300][5225,718s] GC(84) Humongous regions: 48->27
[2019-08-16T14:14:32.681+0300][5225,718s] GC(84) Metaspace: 52818K->52818K(1097728K)
[2019-08-16T14:14:32.681+0300][5225,718s] GC(84) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 7014M->2913M(8192M) 350,496ms
[2019-08-16T14:14:32.681+0300][5225,718s] GC(84) User=0,17s Sys=0,00s Real=0,36s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeap.

Eventually, I haven't seen a proper log, but I add a swap file and finally solr has done the import. Hope this will help someone.